# Oracle SELECT Subquery

Tags: oracle

I have two tables. One for transaction list and one for reference

```
Transaction:


ID | Agency ID | Advertiser ID | Code
1  | 123       | 440           | samplecode

Reference:

ID  | LongName    | Type
123 | Agency1     | Agency
440 | Advertiser1 | Advertiser
```

How can I write the SQL Subquery in Oracle such that I can include the LongName and the Type in the SELECT statement in the transaction table so that it will look like this:

```
ID | Agency ID | LongName | Type   | Advertiser ID | LongName    | Type       | Code
1  | 123       | Agency1  | Agency | 440           | Advertiser1 | Advertiser | samplecode
```

Comment: think it's a good practice to downvote a question if user just want a right answer and don't accept it

Comment: just accepted it.

Comment: @oreh - please don't think that. Downvotes are for reflecting the quality or value of the question (or answer) not for judging a somebody's behaviour.

Comment: ok. thx for the comment

Comment: @oreh can you remove the downvote? as APC said, downvotes are for reflecting the quality of the question or answer. My question and the answer below is of quality and can be a reference for anyone who may face the similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join `Transaction` to `Reference` twice:

```
SELECT
    t.ID,
    t."Agency ID",
    r1.LongName AS ln1,
    r1.Type AS type1,
    t."Advertiser ID",
    r2.LongName AS ln2,
    r2.Type AS type2,
    t.Code
FROM Transaction t
INNER JOIN Reference r1
    ON t."Agency ID" = r1.ID
INNER JOIN Reference r2
    ON t."Advertiser ID" = r2.ID
```